# Creating responsive html table using CSS grid and gathering data from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create some kind of logbook. The idea is that I want it to be responsive, using CSS grids, and in the same time I want to add data to the logbook from JavaScript. I did it with divs, it works fine but at the part in which I am trying to duplicate the row with the new data from JavaScript, I had no solution so I went up with tables. This is how it looks now, but it's not using fully CSS grid and I need a solution.

```js
static addFlightToList(flight) {
  const list = document.querySelector("#gridcontainer");
  const row = document.createElement("tr");


  row.className = "grid-container paddingleft";
  row.innerHTML = `
        <td class="grid-item">${flight.nrcrt}</td>
        <td class="grid-item">${flight.pilot}</td>
        <td class="grid-item">${flight.copilot}</td>
        <td class="grid-item">${flight.takeoff}</td>
        <td class="grid-item">${flight.landing}</td>
        <td class="grid-item">${flight.blocktime}</td>
        <td class="grid-item">${flight.type}</td>
        <td class="grid-item">${flight.comment}</td>
        `;

  list.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(25px, auto);
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(12, 5%, auto);
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: medium;
}
```

```html
<table class="width">
  <thead>
    <tr class="grid-container paddingleft">
      <th class="grid-item">Nr.Crt</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Pilot</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Copilot</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Takeoff</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Landing</th>
      <th class="grid-item">BlockTime</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Type</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="gridcontainer"></tbody>
</table>
```

And this is how the website looks (you can see the text overlapping in the list):

[image: logbook]

I would be grateful if somebody can figure out this for me. I am open to do this in different styles, but I want to keep using CSS grids.

Comment: the question makes no sense. CSS-Grid is all about not using a HTML table in the first place. Why use a HTML table amrkup if you itnend to use CSS-Grid? So far to me, it looks like tabular data. As such a table would be the right use. CSS-Grid is for styling pupose if you want to style a table like layout not if you want to display tabular data.

Comment: I tried using divs but at the javascript part, I don't know how to duplicate them to make new individual rows with the same proprierties.

Comment: like I said, you trying to display tabular data. As such you shouldnt use CSS-Grid in the first place. you not trying to style different elements in a table like layout, you trying to display data inside a table. So use a correct HTML table in the first place. use `innerHTML` and `++`  to add more element to the innerHTML instead of replacing it.

Comment: sorry meant `+=` in my last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tabular data. As such you should forget about CSS-Grid which is a tool for styling purpose. Its for styling elements in a table-like layout not for creating a table. You should use a HTML table to display data.

The thing you are struggeling with is to add more content to the `innerHTML`. This is caused by 2 major issues:

1. You overwrite your existing `innerHTML` instead of adding more content. To add more conntent you have to use `.innerHTML += ...`. The `+=` instead of just `=` adds content instead of replacing it.
2. you have line-breaks within your script. That causes an unexpected line-break error. If you use a linebreak within your code you have to put the line in quotationmarks and add a `+` at the end if more lines will follow:

```js
function addMore() {
  document.querySelector('#gridcontainer').innerHTML += 
    '<td class="grid-item">${flight.nrcrt}</td>' +
    '<td class="grid-item">${flight.pilot}</td>' +
    '<td class="grid-item">${flight.copilot}</td>' +
    '<td class="grid-item">${flight.takeoff}</td>' +
    '<td class="grid-item">${flight.landing}</td>' +
    '<td class="grid-item">${flight.blocktime}</td>' +
    '<td class="grid-item">${flight.type}</td>' +
    '<td class="grid-item">${flight.comment}</td>';
}
```

```html
<table class="width">
  <thead>
    <tr class="grid-container paddingleft">
      <th class="grid-item">Nr.Crt</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Pilot</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Copilot</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Takeoff</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Landing</th>
      <th class="grid-item">BlockTime</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Type</th>
      <th class="grid-item">Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="gridcontainer"></tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="addMore()">Add more entries</button>
```